# Aliasing in Laravel not working?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I wish to call my model (file.php). At the top of my namespaced class I use:

```
use \file as mFile;
use \File;
```

I then can do stuff like:

```
mFile::orderBy('name')->paginate(10);
```

But if I use the laravel File class before I use the model:

```
File::get($test->getRealPath())
mFile::orderBy('name')->paginate(10);
```

The model fails to work, as it tries to access this instead of the model:

```
Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem
```

Why is it doing this?

Comment: Long-story-short, be careful when trying to name models the same as existing Laravel classes, chances are you'll just get an error, but it could all go horribly wrong :P

Answer (score 2):

To php `\File` and `\file` is the same class. PHP classes are case-insensitive.

I suggest you namespace your model like `Acme\File` to avoid this problem. It is also convention to have all classes by camel cased.

Hope this helps